# Trying to output a 2D list using Joins not working

Tags: python, list

I want to join the blank spaces with the elements of the list
i have  used list comprehension, I think that if where the problem is but,
I am unable to find where I am going wrong
INPUT:

```
li = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[9,10,11]]
n = 3
for row in li:
    output = ' '.join([str(ele)] for ele in row)
    print(output)
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f696c49ae010> in <module>
      2 n = 3
      3 for row in li:
----> 4     output = ' '.join([str(ele)] for ele in row)
      5     print(output)

<ipython-input-25-f696c49ae010> in <genexpr>(.0)
      2 n = 3
      3 for row in li:
----> 4     output = ' '.join([str(ele)] for ele in row)
      5     print(output)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you assigned to `str` before?

Comment: I am trying to use the str function

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 10, 11]]
n = 3
for element in data:
    output = ' '.join([str(val) for val in element])
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your for loop inside a list, it works...

```
li = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[9,10,11]]
# n = 3 --> unused 
for row in li:
    output = ' '.join([str(ele) for ele in row])
    print(output)
```